# Raising subsequent alarm()

Tags: c, signals, posix

While trying to reproduce a completely unrelated presumed false positive stack-buffer-overflow warning from asan, I noticed something odd. When I ask for two alarm() signals subsequently, the second apparently never fires. Why is that?

Here is a MWE:

```
#include <setjmp.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static jmp_buf jump_buffer;

void f()
{
    while(true) {};
}

void handle_timeout(int)
{
    longjmp(jump_buffer, 1);
}

void test()
{
    if (setjmp(jump_buffer) == 0)
    {
            f();
    }
}

int main()
{
    signal (SIGALRM, handle_timeout);
    alarm(2);
    test();
    signal (SIGALRM, handle_timeout);
    alarm(2);
    test();
    return 0;
}
```

If you uncomment the second call to `test`, the program terminates as intended after 2s, but as it is it runs forever.

I am well aware that the "signal is automatically blocked [...] during the time the handler is running" according to [gnu.org](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Blocking-for-Handler.html#Blocking-for-Handler), but is that time not ended by `longjump()`?

Comment: The `longjmp` function is *not* a signal-safe function. Use [`sigsetjmp`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sigsetjmp.html) and [`siglongjmp`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/siglongjmp.html) instead. Or a better less spaghetti-like solution.

Comment: You'd probably do better using `sigaction()` — at least you could control the behaviour precisely.  The specification for `signal()` is loosey-goosey because there are/were so many divergent implementations that needed to be matched to the standard.  You don't mention which o/s you're on; the result I get on macOS is unlikely to be the same as the result you get on Linux if you're using Linux.  You don't show how you know that the first alarm goes off, or that the first `test()` completes.  Presumably, the second is interpreted as MIA because the program doesn't stop.

Comment: You could safely and sanely use `pause()` in place of `f()`.

Comment: I'm more than "a bit surprised", but I am able to reproduce the problem on macOS High Sierra 10.13.2.  My somewhat instrumented version of the code uses `pause()` in place of a spin-loop, and uses `sigsetjmp()` and `siglongjmp()`, but it recovers from the first alarm and never receives the second.  On a Mac, `alarm()` is documented in section 3 (functions) and not section 2 (system calls).  It shouldn't make a difference, but the man page indicates that `setitimer()` is in use under the covers.  Are you working on a Mac, by any chance?

Comment: Thinking about this a bit — I've not monitored the signal mask before and after.  I'm left wondering if there is something up there, so the SIGALRM is being suppressed somehow after the signal.  Also, when I removed the `sigsetjmp()`/`siglongjmp()` calls, the second alarm was delivered (it worked) — it appears that the non-local gotos have an effect.  I was using `sigsetjmp()` with `0` as the last parameter.  And when I changed that to `1`, then the code worked with the `sigsetjmp()`/`siglongjmp()` code.   So, I think it is some combination of non-local goto and signal masks that give trouble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I noted in comments, in general it is better to use [`sigaction()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sigaction.html) rather than
[`signal()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/signal.html) because it gives you more precise control over how the signal handling is done.  It is also better to use [`pause()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pause.html)
(at least in non-threaded applications) to wait until some signal arrives than it is to make the CPU spin its wheels in a tight infinite loop.

As [Some programmer dude](https://stackoverflow.com/users/440558/some-programmer-dude) noted in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48061567/raising-subsequent-alarm#comment83095653_48061567), it is better to use [`sigsetjmp()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sigsetjmp.html) and
[`siglongjmp()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/siglongjmp.html) than to use [`setjmp()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/setjmp.html) and
[`longjmp()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/longjmp.html).

However, to my considerable surprise, I am able to reproduce the problem on macOS High Sierra 10.13.2. My instrumented version of the code uses `pause()` in place of a spin-loop, and uses `sigsetjmp()` (with a `savemask` argument of `0`) and `siglongjmp()`, and it recovers from the first alarm and never receives the second. On a Mac, [`alarm()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/alarm.html) is documented in section 3 (functions) and not section 2 (system calls). It shouldn't make a difference, but the man page indicates that [`setitimer()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/setitimer.html) is in use under the covers.

When I removed the `sigsetjmp()`/`siglongjmp()` calls, the second alarm was delivered (it worked) — so it appears that the non-local gotos have an effect. I was using `sigsetjmp()` with 0 as the last parameter. When I changed that to 1, then the code worked with the `sigsetjmp()`/`siglongjmp()` code. So, I think it is some combination of non-local goto and signal masks that give trouble.

Here's a variant of your code with rather extensive instrumentation.  It uses my preferred error reporting functions, which are
available on GitHub in my [SOQ](https://github.com/jleffler/soq) (Stack
Overflow Questions) repository as files `stderr.c` and `stderr.h` in the
[src/libsoq](https://github.com/jleffler/soq/tree/master/src/libsoq)
sub-directory.  Those make it easy to report the times when messages are reported, etc, which is beneficial.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <setjmp.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include "stderr.h"

static bool use_jmpbuf = false;
static int  save_mask  = 1;
static sigjmp_buf jump_buffer;

static void handle_timeout(int signum)
{
    assert(signum == SIGALRM);
    if (use_jmpbuf)
        siglongjmp(jump_buffer, 1);
}

static void handle_sigint(int signum)
{
    err_error("Got signal %d (SIGINT)\n", signum);
    /*NOTREACHED*/
}

static void test(void)
{
    err_remark("Entering %s()\n", __func__);
    if (use_jmpbuf)
    {
        if (sigsetjmp(jump_buffer, save_mask) == 0)
        {
            err_remark("Pausing in %s()\n", __func__);
            pause();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        err_remark("Pausing in %s()\n", __func__);
        pause();
    }
    err_remark("Leaving %s()\n", __func__);
}

static void set_sigalrm(void)
{
    void (*handler)(int) = signal(SIGALRM, handle_timeout);
    if (handler == SIG_ERR)
        err_syserr("signal failed: ");
    if (handler == SIG_IGN)
        err_remark("SIGALRM was ignored\n");
    else if (handler == SIG_DFL)
        err_remark("SIGALRM was defaulted\n");
    else
        err_remark("SIGALRM was being handled\n");
}

static const char optstr[] = "hjm";
static const char usestr[] = "[-hjm]";
static const char hlpstr[] =
    "  -h  Print this help information and exit\n"
    "  -j  Use sigsetjmp()\n"
    "  -m  Do not save signal mask when using sigsetjmp\n"
    ;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    err_setarg0(argv[0]);
    int opt;
    while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, optstr)) != -1)
    {
        switch (opt)
        {
        case 'h':
            err_help(usestr, hlpstr);
            /*NOTREACHED*/
        case 'j':
            use_jmpbuf = true;
            break;
        case 'm':
            use_jmpbuf = true;
            save_mask = 0;
            break;
        default:
            err_usage(usestr);
            /*NOTREACHED*/
        }
    }
    if (optind != argc)
        err_usage(usestr);

    signal(SIGINT, handle_sigint);
    err_setlogopts(ERR_MILLI);
    err_stderr(stdout);

    if (use_jmpbuf)
        err_remark("Config: using sigsetjmp() %s saving signal mask\n", save_mask ? "with" : "without");
    else
        err_remark("Config: no use of sigsetjmp\n");
    set_sigalrm();
    unsigned left;

    left = alarm(2);
    err_remark("Left over from previous alarm: %u\n", left);
    test();
    err_remark("In %s() once more\n", __func__);
    set_sigalrm();
    left = alarm(2);
    err_remark("Left over from previous alarm: %u\n", left);
    test();
    err_remark("Exiting %s() once more\n", __func__);
    return 0;
}
```

Sample runs (program name `alrm61`):

```
$ alrm61 -h
Usage: alrm61 [-hjm]
  -h  Print this help information and exit
  -j  Use sigsetjmp()
  -m  Do not save signal mask when using sigsetjmp
$ alrm61
alrm61: 2018-01-02 21:34:01.893 - Config: no use of sigsetjmp
alrm61: 2018-01-02 21:34:01.894 - SIGALRM was defaulted
alrm61: 2018-01-02 21:34:01.894 - Left over from previous alarm: 0
alrm61: 2018-01-02 21:34:01.894 - Entering test()
alrm61: 2018-01-02 21:34:01.894 - Pausing in test()
alrm61: 2018-01-02 21:34:03.898 - Leaving test()
alrm61: 2018-01-02 21:34:03.898 - In main() once more
alrm61: 2018-01-02 21:34:03.898 - SIGALRM was being handled
alrm61: 2018-01-02 21:34:03.898 - Left over from previous alarm: 0
alrm61: 2018-01-02 21:34:03.898 - Entering test()
alrm61: 2018-01-02 21:34:03.898 - Pausing in test()
alrm61: 2018-01-02 21:34:05.902 - Leaving test()
alrm61: 2018-01-02 21:34:05.902 - Exiting main() once more
$ alrm61 -j
alrm61: 2018-01-02 21:34:23.103 - Config: using sigsetjmp() with saving signal mask
alrm61: 2018-01-02 21:34:23.104 - SIGALRM was defaulted
alrm61: 2018-01-02 21:34:23.104 - Left over from previous alarm: 0
alrm61: 2018-01-02 21:34:23.104 - Entering test()
alrm61: 2018-01-02 21:34:23.104 - Pausing in test()
alrm61: 2018-01-02 21:34:25.108 - Leaving test()
alrm61: 2018-01-02 21:34:25.108 - In main() once more
alrm61: 2018-01-02 21:34:25.108 - SIGALRM was being handled
alrm61: 2018-01-02 21:34:25.108 - Left over from previous alarm: 0
alrm61: 2018-01-02 21:34:25.109 - Entering test()
alrm61: 2018-01-02 21:34:25.109 - Pausing in test()
alrm61: 2018-01-02 21:34:27.112 - Leaving test()
alrm61: 2018-01-02 21:34:27.112 - Exiting main() once more
$ alrm61 -m
alrm61: 2018-01-02 21:34:37.578 - Config: using sigsetjmp() without saving signal mask
alrm61: 2018-01-02 21:34:37.578 - SIGALRM was defaulted
alrm61: 2018-01-02 21:34:37.578 - Left over from previous alarm: 0
alrm61: 2018-01-02 21:34:37.578 - Entering test()
alrm61: 2018-01-02 21:34:37.578 - Pausing in test()
alrm61: 2018-01-02 21:34:39.584 - Leaving test()
alrm61: 2018-01-02 21:34:39.584 - In main() once more
alrm61: 2018-01-02 21:34:39.584 - SIGALRM was being handled
alrm61: 2018-01-02 21:34:39.584 - Left over from previous alarm: 0
alrm61: 2018-01-02 21:34:39.584 - Entering test()
alrm61: 2018-01-02 21:34:39.584 - Pausing in test()
^Calrm61: 2018-01-02 21:35:00.638 - Got signal 2 (SIGINT)
$
```

Comment: `sigsetjmp` is documented as *The sigsetjmp()/siglongjmp() function pairs save and restore the signal
     mask if the argument savemask is non-zero; otherwise, only the register
     set and the stack are saved.*, thus after the first delivery mask contains SIGALARM as code exits handler by `siglongjmp`. If you use non nul mask in call to `sigsetjmp` code behaves correctly. You can also observe the value of the mask in between the calls.

Answer (score 2):

Rewrite the code with `sigset*`and non-active wait (`pause`)  as suggested by Jonathan Leffler:

```
static sigjmp_buf jump_buffer;

void f() {
  pause();
}

void handle_timeout(int sig) {
  siglongjmp(jump_buffer, 1);
}

void test() {
  if (sigsetjmp(jump_buffer,0) == 0) // SAVE or NOT...
    {
      f();
    }
}

int main() {
  printf("1\n");
  signal (SIGALRM, handle_timeout);
  alarm(2);
  test();
  sigset_t m;
  sigprocmask(0,NULL,&m);
  printf("%d\n",m);
  printf("2\n");
  signal (SIGALRM, handle_timeout);
  alarm(2);
  test();
  return 0;
}
```

Then execution is blocked on the second part because exiting the handler with a `jmp` doesn't restores the mask, and as `signal` blocks the currently delivered signal then after the first call to `test()` signal mask contains `SIGALRM` which is then blocked, see execution:

```
$ ./test
1
8192 #SIGALRM
2    <-blocked
```

Now if change value 0 to 1 (line commented as SAVE or NOT) as documentation about `sigsetjmp` says:

> The sigsetjmp()/siglongjmp() function pairs save and restore the
>   signal mask if the argument savemask is non-zero; otherwise, only the register
>        set and the stack are saved.

the signal mask after the first call to test is restored, see execution:

```
$ ./test
1
0
2
$
```